# Debounced submission of form in onChange

Tags: redux-form

I have a field like this:

```
{
    render() {

        return <Field type="text" onChange={this.debouncedSubmit} />

        ....
    }
    debouncedSubmit = debounce(this.props.submit, 500)
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'week-form',
    onSubmit: async function() {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000))
    }
})
```

This works fine except for one issue. We see here submission takes 5 seconds. We see also that deboucne is 500ms. So lets say user typed in two characters, then waited 1sec. The debounce triggered and submission is in process. Now while submission is in process, lets say user inputs another character. This triggers debounce, and at time 1.5sec it triggers submit. However because submission is currently in progress, this one gets missed.

Is there a pattern with redux-form to not miss this?

#### What I tried:

I thought to "reinitialize" the form, but "do not update field value if current field value differs from value it is about to initialize with", and then in componentDidUpdate if form is dirty, then I would trigger submit again. However Im running into a problem:

I set in reduxForm:

```
enableReinitialize: true,
keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true,
```

And I initialize the form with data. However after the first submission, for some reason it overwrites the field and I lose the "third character" i put in while submission was going on. Why is this happening when I set keepDirtyOnReinitialize to true.

Answer (score 0):

So actually my logic above works. I created a demo here on the web and it works perfectly:

https://codesandbox.io/s/37z9217q6

The problem is I am doing this in react-native on Android and there is a bug there that is causing this problem for me, I filed the bug - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19085